# VBA Macro stops working on new computer

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

So I got a new computer at work and now my macro doesn't run. Supposedly all the settings and programs are the same as the old one. The macro opens and addresses the emails properly, but doesn't paste in the data before sending. My co-worker tried it on their machine and it works EXCEPT for the first one (doesn't paste). I'm stumped!

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    'Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim MItem As Object
    'Dim MItem As Outlook.MailItem

    'Create Outlook object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("APP").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Sendrng.Copy

    'Create Mail Item
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    'Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With MItem
        .To = "xxx@xxx.com"
        .Subject = "APP High Cash"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        '.Body = "a"
        .Display
        Wait 2
    End With
    SendKeys "^({v})", True
    Wait 2
    With MItem
        .Send
    End With

    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set MItem = Nothing


    'Create Outlook object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Angie").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Sendrng.Copy

    'Create Mail Item
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    'Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With MItem
        .To = "xxx@xxx.com"
        .Subject = "High Cash"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        '.Body = "a"
        .Display
        Wait 2
    End With
    SendKeys "^({v})", True
    Wait 2
    With MItem
        .Send
    End With

    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set MItem = Nothing

    'Create Outlook object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Cathy").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Sendrng.Copy

    'Create Mail Item
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    'Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With MItem
        .To = "xxx@xxx.com"
        .Subject = "High Cash"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        '.Body = "a"
        .Display
        Wait 2
    End With
    SendKeys "^({v})", True
    Wait 2
    With MItem
        .Send
    End With

    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set MItem = Nothing

    'Create Outlook object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Corey").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Sendrng.Copy

    'Create Mail Item
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    'Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With MItem
        .To = "xxx@xxx.com"
        .Subject = "High Cash"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        '.Body = "a"
        .Display
        Wait 2
    End With
    SendKeys "^({v})", True
    Wait 2
    With MItem
        .Send
    End With

    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set MItem = Nothing

'Create Outlook object
    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Curt").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Sendrng.Copy

    'Create Mail Item
    Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    'Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With MItem
        .To = "xxx@xxx.com"
        .Subject = "High Cash"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        '.Body = "a"
        .Display
        Wait 2
    End With
    SendKeys "^({v})", True
    Wait 2
    With MItem
        .Send
    End With

    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    Set MItem = Nothing


End Sub
```

**Sub Wait:**

```
Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like a silly answer but try copying the code into new modules and run them again.

Comment: This might be a very obvious question ... but I'll ask it anyways .... does your new computer have Outlook and Office apps installed on it?

Comment: Is it the same version of Windows and the same version of Excel?

Comment: Same versions of Windows and Office.

Comment: Sorry to come back to an old thread, but it's not working again. Same problem...

Comment: Some more detail: It worked perfect on my old computer. My new computer does everything correct, excpet the pasting in the email before sending. I had a co-worker try it on their machine and consistently it works fine but sends out just the first email blank! What the heck. All 3 machines have same versions of Outlook and Office. Any ideas?!

Comment: For anyone following: I think I fixed it for my machine. I added the wait command after the copy and it works now on my machine. For my co-worker, it still doesn't paste just the first one. Still stumped on that one...

Answer (score 0):

Your `SendKeys` statement looks wrong... why the round parentheses? I mean, what have them to do with the [CTRL]+[V] sequence?

Try:

```
SendKeys "^{v}", True
```

in the several places where you paste.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone following: I think I fixed it for my machine. I added the wait command after the copy and it works now on my machine. For my co-worker, it still doesn't paste just the first one. Still stumped on that one...